# Change the title color of a navigation item in Xcode 11.4

Tags: swift, navigationitem, xcode11.4

I cannot change the title color of a navigation item. It is an old project with support for iOS 10.0+.

Setting the title:

```
navigationItem.title = "My Title"
```

Someone changed the property `titleColor` (in `Title Text Attributes`) of a navigation bar in a storyboard. And now it doesn't work. It is strange because it works in Xcode 11.3.1, but doesn't work in Xcode 11.4.

Attempts to change the title color:

1. `navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
   NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.mainGold ]` (also I
   tried different keys here)
2. `navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor =
   UIColor.mainGold` (also tried `barTintColor` :D)

I tried to add it in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc

I tried it with `UINavigationBar.appeareance()` in `AppDelegate`. And it works in an empty project. It also works for the navigation item title in my first view controller.

There are a lot of screens in my project, and something blocks changing the title color. The title color of a navigation item is always white (for dark theme) or black (for light theme).

It does confuse me.

Screenshot of the view hierarchy. `UILabel LUXURIES` is the title of a navigation item:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated Xcode to version 11.4.1 (11E503a) and it fixed the issue.

I think it was a strange Xcode bug. I tried to reproduce it in an empty project, but I couldn't.

Comment: It also affected navigation bar background colors and bar title colors. All sorts of weird stuff in 11.4 which is now thankfully gone in 11.4.1.